# How to activate Fn+F9 hotkeys to disable touchpad on Asus X55A laptop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, touchpad, hotkeys

How to activate `Fn + F9` hotkeys to disable touchpad on Asus X55A laptop? (Windows 7). I tried reinstall (repair) ATKACPI driver, but this not help. 
I have no ASUS Smart Gesture Touchpad Driver or Elantech Touchpad driver installed, because don't need various advanced features, sinse existing options if fully enough for me. Do I need install any of these drivers in order just to disable touchpad?